# create symfony project using the symfony installer

Tags: php, symfony

i used to to use composer to create a new symfony project like so

```
composer create-project symfony/symfony-standard-edition SymfonyProjectDir 2.5.*
```

but know when i want to use the symfony installer i use the command

```
symfony new SymfonyProjectDir 2.5.*
```

or

```
symfony new SymfonyProjectDir 2.5
```

but i get this error

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                 
  The Symfony version should be 2.N.M, where N = 0..9 and M = 0..99  

new directory [version]
```

how can i tel that i want to use the version 2.5 including the last updates from symfony like i used to with composer?

Comment: have a look at this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#basing-your-project-on-a-specific-symfony-version

Comment: yes i know, but how can i get a specific version with the latest updates, do i have to find out myself?

Comment: If you're using a non current version like 2.5 then you just need to look up the release notes surely

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull they should handle that, what if i want to use version 2.3 do i need to look up the release notes to, why they don't just include the * at the end like composer ...!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to have the latest minor version of an version. You start developing with the latest version and then you should freeze it until there is a reason to update.

If you don't care, clone the git repo, `grep` your tag and create your project with it.

Comment: what do you mean by `grep` your tag?

Comment: `grep` is a command line tool for linux. Maybe this works: if the version and tag format in git is x.x.x, then you can `git tag --list | tail -1` and get your latest version. since `git clone` checks the master out you can do a sparse checkout since git 1.7 with a `git config core.sparsecheckout true` before clone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it worked for me:

[Symfony Installation and Project Creation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)

Or just open command line and execute these commands:

> for (linux/mac)

```
sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
symfony new SymfonyProjectDir 2.5
```

> The version will be the most recent version in 2.5, as you want

Answer (score 1):

Last answer here is from 2016 so if you end up here somehow in 2019 the solution is much easier!

First make sure you are using a php version of 7.1 or higher.
Check if you have composer installed and if you don't just follow this easy documentation: [Download/Install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Now you are all set, go to the directory where you want your symfony project be stored and enter the command `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project`. This will create your first structure in symfony 4!

Now you just enter your project directory and type `php bin/console server:run` on your terminal and you are done. 
You can import repositories from git too starting `git init` from the same project folder.

First time with Symfony? Follow this tutorial for a first controller/view: [Introduction to symfony4](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/637/introduction-to-symfony-4-creating-your-first-hello-world-application)

Hope this if somehow usefull to anyone, i'm just trying to give something back to this community that has given me so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with it:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition SymfonyProjectDir/ 3.0.7
```

It should work. Maybe your forgot the last slash...